# J Query Many Buttons on a page

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a quiz blog where I am using the J query Toggle Button to show answers of a question. I use the following pattern:

```
Question: 1
<script type="text/javascript">$(function(){$("#butToggle1").click(function(){$('#dvt1').toggle(500);});});</script> 
<div id="dvt1">
Answer
</p></div> <button id="butToggle1">Click for Answer</button>

Question 2
<script type="text/javascript">$(function(){$("#butToggle2").click(function(){$('#dvt2').toggle(500);});});</script> 
<div id="dvt2">
Text 2
</p></div> <button id="butToggle2">Click for Answer</button>
```

I am using jquery-1.3.2.min.js for the above functionality. 
However, the problem is that to show a number of questions and answers on a page, I have to add that many dvt entries to the css. I have added from dvt1 to dvt20, but this means that I can not show 21 questions on a page. Then, I can not assort the questions because a conflict of same dvt would leave the toggle function to not to work.

Is there any way that I can show many toggle buttons on a wordpress post without having separate dvt, butToggle numbers assigned to each of them.

Thanks for your help

Comment: how many scripts tag  you are using ? only one is enough

Comment: Kindly check it here:[link]http://bit.ly/10vJGKs

Answer (score 1):

I think just using only this code once, in a **single** script tag would be fine:

```
$(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    $(this).prev('div').toggle(500);
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ayecJ/embedded/result/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use just one script to this: http://jsfiddle.net/GP3M6/

```
$("button").click(function () {
  $(this).prev('div').toggle(500);
});
```